# Analytic continuation of a function containing the sgn-function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $f(z)$ and infinitely many of its values $f(i \omega$) along the imaginary axis are known. It has its roots in physics: at a finite temperature $T>0$, the $\omega$ are called Matsubara frequencies and are given by
$$ \omega_n = \pi T (2n+1), \; n \in \mathbb{Z} $$
In the low-temperature limit $T \rightarrow 0$ these frequencies turn into continuous values. I would like to perform the analytic continuation to the real axis. There are two possibilities, the continuation from below (replace $i \omega$ with $\omega + i 0_-$) or the continuation from above (replace $i\omega$ with $\omega + i 0_+$). I want to use the latter. But now the function is of the form
$$ f(i \omega) = \frac{1}{i \omega + i \mathrm{sgn}(\omega) A - V}, $$
where $A, V$ are real constants. I am a bit confused as how to perform the analytic continuation because I am interested in the continuation to $0$ and I do not know how to handle the sign-function.

I think, it's important to know how I arrived at the function mentioned above. There is a complex function $g_a(z)$ given and I evaluate it at $i\omega$ and afterwards perform a certain limit ($a \rightarrow \infty$):
$$g_a(i \omega) \rightarrow g_\infty(i \omega).$$
Now, $f$ is given by
$$f(i \omega) = \frac{1}{g_\infty(i \omega) - V},$$
which gives the function above.

Comment: You have values at what points exactly? The location of the points may change the problem. If the infinitely many points do not accumulate anywhere there is going to be solution, if they accumulate somewhere there may be only one, or none. You provide the function you got. Does that mean you were given the values for every $iw$? If that is the case, that function is discontinuous at the real axis. There is no much hope.

Comment: I added some information to my post, because it was not written well at all. And I think I have also found my answer. In order to perform the analytic continuation of $f$ I just have to perform the continuation of $g_a(i \omega \rightarrow \omega + i 0_+)$ and then take the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$. This way I get an extended function $\tilde f$ which agrees with $f$ on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Ah, it is a discrete set of points where you have the values. Do you know the method to use [Weirstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) to build an entire function with specified values at certain points? I have to go to my office now, later I might write how it goes. It is a bit longer than just a comment. There is never much hope in getting a nice closed formula, but the good thing is that there is a clear path to get the answer.

Comment: No, the method using the Weierstrass factorization theorem is new to me. But I am looking at the zero temperature limit, so this set of points is no longer discrete.